# Configuring implicit TLS over FTP in Synapse VFS transport

Tags: wso2, ssl, ftps, vfs, apache-synapse

We need to connect to a ftp-server which only allows implicit TLS over FTP on port 990. We are using WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 which support ftps and is built on the [Synapse project](http://synapse.apache.org).

An example configuration in WSO2 for ftps can be [found here](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/01/wso2-esb-example-file-exchanging-hub-part-1#read-ftps).

We are not able to find a way to configure our client to use implicit TLS over FTP. What we understand from the VFS documentation, the [configuration defaults to explicit mode](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/ftps/FtpsFileSystemConfigBuilder.html#getFtpsType%28org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions%29).

Does anyone know how to set implicit mode?